# Component JTable ignores setDbo() and don't save row

Tags: joomla-2.5, jtable

I have component called "MyComponent" and table class called "MyComponentTableSample". In model I create instance to table:

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Sample', 'MyComponentTable');
```

then I want to setDBO

```
$table->setDBO($this->getTargetLanguageDbo());
```

and execute table's method that contains:

```
$row = new stdClass();
$row->primary_key = 1;
$row->field_name = "something";
$this->bind($row);
$this->store(TRUE);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't insert/update row in database. I checked and `bind()` and `store()` return true. When I call out `$this->_db` from table's method, it returns me

```
["_database":"JDatabase":private]=>
  string(20) "my_databaseName"
```

what is correct and it means dbo has been set, but still there is no row in database. `$this->getErrors()` from table returns empty array

Comment: just a quick suggestion, try replacing $this with $table.

Comment: I think you are right. It should be an answer.

Comment: No, it's not a problem. $this I'm using in my table what extends JTable so it's ok.

Comment: `JTable->setDBO($db)` expects a JDatabaseDriver object. Are you sure your `$this->getTargetLanguageDbo()` returns the right object ?